# Get JSON element as string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I want the JSON array element to be converted as a string.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":373313181,
      "from":"no-reply@email.com",
      "subject":"example subject 123",
      "date":"2022-01-06 13:22:14"
   }
]
```

I want to get the ID element as a string.

I tried to do like that:

```cs
var json = "[{\"id\":373313181,\"from\":\"no-reply@email.com\",\"subject\":\"example subject 123\",\"date\":\"2022-01-06 13:22:14\"}]";
var parse = JObject.Parse(json);
var id = parse["id"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(id);
```

So that the output will be like this:

> 373313181

But that simply just didn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: What did happen when you tried that? You need to parse as an array, not a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Parse as `JArray` and take the first element of the array.

```cs
var json = "[{\"id\":373313181,\"from\":\"no-reply@email.com\",\"subject\":\"example subject 123\",\"date\":\"2022-01-06 13:22:14\"}]";
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
var id = (string)array[0]["id"];
```

And from your question, cast the id to `string` as below:

```cs
var id = (string)array[0]["id"];
```

OR

```cs
var id = array[0]["id"].Value<string>();
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UR2bsp)

Comment: It works well. But when I do like this:
`{\"id\":373335829,\"from\":\"no reply@email.com\",\"subject\":\"blabla\",\"date\":\"2022 - 01 - 0614:04:27\",\"attachments\":[],\"body\":\"blabla\",\"textBody\":\"blabla\",\"htmlBody\":\"\"}`
It says Current JsonReader item is not an array
`var id2 = array2[5]["body"].ToString();`

Comment: Your new JSON is not an array. `var obj= JObject.Parse(json); var body = obj["body"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

My implementation:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
        
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{\"id\":373313181,\"from\":\"no-reply@email.com\",\"subject\":\"example subject 123\",\"date\":\"2022-01-06 13:22:14\"}]";
        dynamic test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(test[0].id));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(test[0].id).GetType());

    }
}

//Output
373313181
System.String
```